# is it Possible to Disable input in teams app for my chatbot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, disabled-input

I'm building a chatbot with microsofts bot framework, nodejs. There are features in the chatbot where at times api call is made to external systems and the user has to wait for about a minute.
I was wondering would it be possible to block/disable the input box of teams during such times.If not many users start talking to the bot when in the back-end API fetch is still running for the previous dialog,which produces undesirable results.

Any idea, disable or maybe block the user any other way???

Comment: you could try send a Typing activity, this is kind of what it's designed for. It won't BLOCK the user, but at least shows them something is in progress

Comment: unfortunately..typing activity is disabled for EU region teams.

Comment: I think it's disabled globally in fact at the moment, because of Covid, so hopefully that should change soon. You could do you own version, by sending something like a "please wait" message, and then updating the content of that message when the action is complete.

Comment: well  i have that in place of course.. But users still have the tendency to type even after the bot asks to plz wait.

Comment: blocking the input box doesnt seem to be a possibility right? Anyway i could stop the dialog from running within Onmessage of activity handler.?. Where it possibly checks for current dialog stack and if its api calls dialogs last step.. stops the user from typing.??

Comment: running out of space, so made a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out of the box way to do this, that I know of, but middleware might help, like if you stored the state of the conversation, and rejected any messages earlier in the middleware pipeline during this period, or maybe sent an "error" message, something like that. Otherwise, have a look at the very latest release of bot framework (4.9), which has some better abilities for "adaptive dialogs" - see https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases